# Twitter Bootstrap - Login/Register/User Management Script

Tags: php, authentication, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap for my new site. I have read tutorials on how to get a working login box that is correctly styled.

Which login script should I use, or should I code one myself? I know some PHP, but am unsure which login script with at least some basic user management is the best?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

UPDATED 19/3/13:

- Fixed broken links, added new example page.
- Added mention about SQL vulerabilities / PDO.

---

Bootstrap offers a CSS framework with associated JavaScript. It doesn't deal with server side code, and you need to do this yourself.

I recently did the same as you, in PHP, and I found the following two links useful, well explained, simple to follow and excellent for beginners.  Combine the two and you'll have what you need.

[BuildInternet.com's basic PHP backend setup, with login, session management etc](http://buildinternet.com/2009/12/creating-your-first-php-application-part-1/) covers:

1. Setting up the project, creating OO database class.
2. Building backend, user class, user tools, login/logout, registration.
3. Building frontend, forms, form handling, displaying session data.

[Simple registration page using Twitter Bootstrap](http://www.9lessons.info/2012/04/bootstrap-registration-form-tutorial.html) contains:

1. [A demo page.](http://demos.9lessons.info/bootstrap/form.php)
2. Basic markup for registration page.
3. A little custom CSS.

**A Note on database security**

BuildInternet.com's tutorial above uses standard mysql_* functions. These are vulnerable to attack and are deprecated.  Once you understand your login page, you should secure your database functionality using [PDO](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html).

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

I have a suggestion if you like, i have got a good php script build in codeigntier HMVC. Can be used as kickstarter for any new project. It has login, reigstration, user management, permission, email templates, installer and many exciting features. May it helps you

http://www.webprojectbuilder.com/item/user-login-and-management